Powershell: replace every line that contains a given string
Suppose I have a text file that contains the following lines:
Apple
Bananas
Fruit things
Oranges
Fruit pieces

I want to replace every line that contains the string "Fruit" with a new line that contains just the string "MoreSpecific". I've worked out the following code:
$File = '\path\to\file.txt'
$Locate = Get-Content $File | Select-String "Fruit" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
(Get-Content $File) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$Locate","MoreSpecific"} | Set-Content $File

...but nothing in the target files is replaced. Running echo $Locate gives the following output:
Fruit things
Fruit pieces

...indicating that both complete lines are being stored in the variable. Now it makes sense, because since no single line contains the entirety of the two lines together, no match is found and no replacement is made. Sure enough, if I remove the second line containing "Fruit", the single remaining line is replaced.
What I need is to perform the line replacement immediately upon finding the matching string, before proceeding to the next match. Advice appreciated!

you want to replace the whole line or just the word Fruit in this case?

The whole line - in this case, both Fruit things and Fruit pieces. I clarified the question.

If I understand correctly you can simplify it a lot:
@'
Apple
Bananas
Fruit things
Oranges
Fruit pieces
'@ -replace 'Fruit.+', 'More specific'

Applied to your code:
(Get-Content $File -Raw) -replace 'Fruit.+', 'More specific' |
    Set-Content $File


If casing is important (if you need to match Fruit with an uppercase F) use -creplace instead of -replace.

If Fruit (the keyword) isn't always starting the line and you still want to replace the whole line, the regex should be .*Fruit.*:
(Get-Content $File -Raw) -replace '.*Fruit.*', 'More specific'




Perhaps I did myself a disservice by simplifying my example too much - I was just trying to make it easy to follow. :) My real use case is to search an XML file of over 7000 lines for a string that appears in the middle of several lines ~100 characters long, and replace the entire line with a similarly sized one. I will adapt my question to better reflect this.

@foolishgrunt isn't that what the last bullet point covers?

I tried modifying my actual script in the manner you suggested, but I got no different results

To be fair to you, my modified question really is going to be something else entirely. I'll just mark you correct and create a new question. :)

@foolishgrunt sounds good, if the actual question was showing actual XML I wouldn't have given a regex answer either (most likely)

@foolishgrunt, as suggested by Santiago, peeking and poking directly into a serialized string (e.g. XML) using string methods (like -Replace) is a bad idea. Instead you should use the related parser for searching and replacing which has an easier syntax and takes care of known issues and pitfalls. See also this answer.

Your description of the real problem sounds a little like a template engine.  You might want to research template engines to see if the concept can be usefully applied to what you are trying to do.  There is a tag called [Template-engine] here in stackoveflow.  Most of the tools discussed in there relate to Python rather than powershell.

Thanks all. The new (and more specific) question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78794663/powershell-add-new-line-after-every-line-that-contains-a-given-string
