Powershell: add new line after every line that contains a given string
I have a >7000 line XML file, which I define as $File, and which contains (scattered throughout all the other lines) four lines exactly as follows:
   <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>

Immediately below each of these lines, I want to add several new lines that I have defined in a separate text file (which I will call with a variable titled $Insert), then write the modified data back to the source file. I figure it's easiest to identify these lines by searching for the string "Page #" (especially because the formatting strings could change in unforeseen ways as the XML is modified).
My thought is that it would be easiest to replace each of these lines with a single string that consists of the the same line that I'm searching for, followed by a line break, followed by the lines given in the $Insert variable (though I am open to better suggestions.) Here's the code that I've worked out so far (and for this example, I'll define $Insert directly as containing line 1 = foo and line 2 = bar):
$Insert = "foo`nbar"
$Locate = Get-Content $File | Select-String "Page #" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
(Get-Content $File) |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $Locate,"$Locate`n$Insert"} | Set-Content $File

What I want is for every instance of the sought-for line would be replaced by the following:
   <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>
foo
bar

Instead, apparently no replacement takes place. Running echo $Locate gives the following output:
   <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T
20">Content</text:span></text:p>    <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:s
pan><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>    <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:sty
le-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>    <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page
 #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>

...that is, the term to be replaced is being defined as the sought-for line repeated four times. Since no single line matches these four lines concatenated, no replacement is made.
What I need is to perform the replacement immediately upon finding a match, and before proceeding to the second match. Advice appreciated!

https://regex101.com/r/wki1Jo/1, and hit Code generator: https://regex101.com/r/wki1Jo/1/codegen?language=csharp  (I hope csharp matches Powershell pretty much.... )

sorry, not able to reproduce, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78794724/724039

I found my solution by abandoning the idea of "-replace". New code:
$Insert = "foo`nbar"
(Get-Content $File) | Foreach-Object { $_ # Pass each line of file through
    if ($_ -match "Page #") { #If the search string is located in this line...
        $Insert} #...insert new lines below
} | Set-Content $File #Write all modified content to the file

Which yields the following lines in the file:
   <text:p text:style-name="P27"><text:span text:style-name="T20">Page #</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T19"><text:tab/></text:span><text:span text:style-name="T20">Content</text:span></text:p>
foo
bar

...everywhere in the file where the search term appears.


Your own solution works, but I suggest using a switch statement for faster line-by-line processing of your file with -File and regex-matching with -Regex:
# On Windows, it is better to use:
#         "foo`r`nbar"
$Insert = "foo`nbar"

Set-Content $File -Value $( # NOTE: Be sure to place $( on the same line as -Value
  switch -File $File -Regex {
    'Page #' { $_; $Insert } # pass through, followed by lines to insert
    default  { $_ } # pass through
  }
)


As in your solution, the changed content is written directly back to the input file, so making a backup copy first is advisable.

In order to be able to replace the input file's content based on the original content, the latter must be read into memory in full first, as in your solution. (Here, it is $(...) that ensures processing of the entire file up front; in your solution, it is (...) around your Get-Content call).

Newline format caveat: In your $Insert definition, you're using `n, i.e. a Unix-format LF-only newline; if you're running the code on Windows, the pass-through lines will be separated with Windows-format CRLF newlines; to avoid mixing different newline formats in your file, either use `r`n on Windows or use the abstraction that provides the host platform-appropriate newline, [Environment]::NewLine, e.g.
'foo{0}bar' -f [Environment]::NewLine

Character-encoding caveat: switch, when passed a file without a BOM, invariably interprets the file as UTF-8-encoded; while this is to be expected in PowerShell (Core) 7, which consistently defaults to UTF-8, it may be surprising in Windows PowerShell, given that Get-Content there defaults to ANSI (the ANSI code page associated with the legacy system locale).



When I run your suggested command, the script stops and prompts me to Supply values for the following parameters: Value[0]:

@foolishgrunt, that implies that you forgot to pass a -Value argument. Note that in order for the argument to be recognized syntactically, the $( part must be on the same line as -Value.

I copied and pasted your code, down to the comments. :)

@foolishgrunt, I just did the same thing, both in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7, and the code works as expected. You can provoke the symptom you're seeing as follows, proving that the absence of a -Value argument is your problem, which isn't present in the code in this answer: Set-Content foo

Okay, I'm using PowerShell version 5. I don't know if that's relevant or not, but if it is, I probably won't pursue this. My goal with this script is to distribute it to my coworkers for easy reuse, and since I'm pretty sure my coworkers also have Powershell 5, I know some will complain about having to upgrade.

@foolishgrunt: No upgrade needed: version 5 (more likely 5.1) is Windows PowerShell, and the code works just fine there.

When I have a little more time (being pulled a bunch of different directions right now), I'll put together a reproducible demo.

I must have made a mistake when I copy/pasted your commands earlier (no surprise to you, I'm sure), b/c I could not reproduce just now. However I do have a different issue, which I suspect is related to your "character encoding caveat": The desired lines were added, but the modified XML (an .fodt file) is unable to be opened ("General I/O error"). I used WinMerge to compare the output files generated by my method (left) and your method (right) and I found a number of lines that differ as shown: https://i.imgur.com/18w4AIX.png
Is there an argument I can pass to make switch use ANSI encoding?

On second thought, I think my better route is to correct whatever formatting in my source file is responsible for this line in the XML: <style:font-face style:name="新細明體" svg:font-family="新細明體" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>. That's what gets interpreted in the ways shown in the screenshot.

@foolishgrunt: Unfortunately, you can not control what character encoding switch -File assumes in the absence of a BOM: it is invariably UTF-8. If you do need to specify a different encoding while providing similar performance, you need to use .NET APIs directly, namely [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(), which does allow you to specify an encoding explicitly.

Finally got it working - I converted the .fodt file using Libreoffice and the "FilterOptions=UTF8,LF" arguments. After doing so, your suggested code processes the file properly, so I suppose I can finally officially consider this a solution. :)
Incidentally, this is part of a larger script. When I run the script calling your code, the process finishes in about 2.68 seconds, while the script calling my code finishes in about 3.03 seconds.

Not able to reproduce (mre):
PS D:\temp> get-content .\abc.csv
"a","b","c"
1,2,3
4,5,replace
7,8,9
1,2,3
4,5,replace
7,8,9
PS D:\temp> (Get-Content .\abc.csv) |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'replace',"replace`nfoor`nbar`n"} | Set-Content .\abc.csv
PS D:\temp> get-content .\abc.csv
"a","b","c"
1,2,3
4,5,replace
foor
bar

7,8,9
1,2,3
4,5,replace
foor
bar

7,8,9
PS D:\temp>


First, you are replacing only the search term, not the entire line containing the search term. Second, there is only one instance of the search term in source file - and my code works for only one match of the search term. It fails when there is more than one.

changed mre to have more than 1 result ....
